# Variable product displays subscription details twice

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Wordpress with Woocommerce and I have created a variable product with subscriptions based on whether they are paying monthly, twice a year or yearly. The product page shows the month or year twice. [month on variable displays twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FxN2.png)
I can see from using the developer tools that it is pulling  / month twice. [span code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh1FO.png) I also have another product displaying a recaptcha input twice. This is a product that is linked using the Appointments Booking Calendar plugin.[double recaptcha on product page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkEZj.png) Does anyone know how to get rid of the second month/year on the product page and the extra recaptcha?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon your question searching for this exact issue, and was bummed there were no answers. After chatting with Woocommerce, they piped me a tidy CSS rule to help hide that second iteration.

```
.single-product .single_variation_wrap .price .subscription-details:nth-child(2) {
display: none;
```

}

Hope this helps someone!

(Note: This is being used in conjunction with the WooCommerce Subscriptions premium plugin found [here](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/).)

Comment: Thanks Noah. I had the same issue. Some products were showing the '/ YEAR' twice, some were not. Very annoying.. Thanks!